# Limit of series of sine terms with random arguments

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits

I have no statistics/probability background, so excuse me if this is a dumb question. Consider the following function:
\begin{align*}
f_N(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n=1}^N \cos(2\pi \vec{k}_n\cdot \vec{x} + \varphi_n)
\end{align*}
where $\varphi_n$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,2 \pi]$ and $\vec{k}_n$ is uniformly distributed on the 2-sphere $S_2$. Is there any way that I can make a statement about how that function will look in the limit of $N \to \infty$?

**Edit:** I encountered this function in my research while trying to simulate the surface of a bicontinuous structure. In something called Cahn's scheme, level sets of this function represent the surface of a randomly assembled bicontinuous structure (e.g. a sponge). The scheme does not mention too much about N's size, so I was wondering how that would look in the limit of large N.

Comment: I don't know how to handle this either, so here are two suggestions based on large amounts of ignorance: (1) use cos(a+b)=cos a cos b-sin a sin b; (2) use cos x = Real(exp(i x)). Also, the central limit theorem comes to mind.

Comment: It is not a dumb question. Where did you encounter it? What is the background of this random variable?

Comment: I will have a look at the central limit theorem, thank you. @Shashi I encountered this in my research simulating a bicontinuous structure through something called Cahn's Scheme, where the surface is a level set of this (or at least a similar) function.The randomness seems key to represent structural features of such a structure (e.g. a sponge). The scheme says little about the size of N, so I was asking myself how that function would look in the limit but couldn't figure out anything useful.

Comment: @Banana interesting that something like this comes out of it. I would advice you to put that in the question, many readers will appreciate it instead of having to look at the comments. And indeed the CLT might help you with this. Good luck!

Comment: @JohnBarber thanks, fixed the typo. Are you sure that its really independent of x? that is rather surprising then (to me)

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I will replace $\varphi_n$ by $\theta_n$ to emphasize that this is a random angle and save the symbol $\varphi$ for other use.

Let $\varphi$ be a compactly supported distribution on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and write $\hat{\varphi}(k) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \varphi(x) e^{-2\pi i k\cdot x} \, dx$ for its Fourier transform. Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\exp\{ i \langle f_N, \varphi \rangle \}
&= \left( \mathbb{E}\exp\left\{ \frac{i}{\sqrt{N}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \varphi(x) \cos(2\pi k_1 \cdot x+\theta_1) \, dx \right\} \right)^N \\
&= \bigg( 1 + \frac{i}{\sqrt{N}} \mathbb{E}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \varphi(x) \cos(2\pi k_1 \cdot x+\theta_1) \, dx \\
&\hspace{4em} - \frac{1}{2N} \mathbb{E}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \varphi(x) \cos(2\pi k_1 \cdot x+\theta_1) \, dx \right)^2 + \mathcal{O}(N^{-3/2}) \bigg)^N \\
&= \left( 1 - \frac{1}{4N} \mathbb{E} \left[ \left| \hat{\varphi}(k_1) \right|^2 \right] + \mathcal{O}(N^{-3/2}) \right)^N \\
&\xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E} \left[ \left| \hat{\varphi}(k_1) \right|^2 \right] \right\} \\
&\hspace{3em} = \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{4} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3} \varphi(x)\varphi(y) \frac{\sin(2\pi|x-y|)}{2\pi|x-y|} \, dxdy \right\}.
\end{align*}

This strongly suggests that $f_N$ will converge in distribution to a Gaussian field with the covariance kernel

$$ C(x, y) = \frac{\operatorname{sinc}(2\pi|x-y|)}{2} = \frac{\sin(2\pi|x-y|)}{4\pi|x-y|}. $$

(Since Lévy's continuity theorem need not hold in general Banach space and I am not an expert of this topic, I will leave this bold claim open.)

Since we may choose $\varphi$ to be a linear combination of finite masses, we at least know that any finite-dimensional distribution of $f_N$ converges in distribution to the normal distribution with covariance matrix $C$, i.e.,

$$ (f_N(x_1), \cdots, f_N(x_d)) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, [C(x_i, x_j)]_{i,j=1}^{d})  $$

Here is a density polt of a simulation of the limit using points $(\frac{i}{10},\frac{j}{10},0)$ for $0 \leq i, j \leq 30$.

$\hspace{8em}$ [image: simulation using mesh size $1/10$ on $[0, 3]^2$]

Comment: that looks promising, but there are a lot of terms I never heard before, so I'm still a little confused. Can you say a few more words about the density plot of a simulation of the limit?   I only found an expression for the "density function in the non-degenerate covariance matrix case", what exactly did you use?

Comment: @Banana, Sorry for the ambiguity. By ‘density plot’ I mean the plot of $(x, y)\mapsto f(x,y,0)$, where each point $(x,y)$ is colored according to the value of $f(x,y,0)$. And here, $f$ is simulated by the above scheme, i.e., I picked points $S=\{(i/10,j/10,0):0\leq i,j\leq30\}$ and sampled $(w_x:x\in S)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,[C(x,y)]_{x,y\in S}])$ and interpolated data $\{(x,w_x):x\in S\}$ to obtain the function $f$. Finally, this method seems not practically useful since the covariance matrix seems badly behving, so computing the inverse is numerically challenging.